# Does Async execute block ui thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am using

```
AsyncTask.execute(() -> {...}
```

in my application and noticed this method blocks the ui thread. I have some code within the body of execute that does some calculations which takes 5 to 8 seconds and then returns the result to the ui via `runOnUiThread`. But it looks like once I call the method which has the Async.execute(..) in it. The UI is blocked from adding other elements until this element has completed its computations and returned result to the ui.

Also the Android docs state:

> This method must be called from the main thread of your app.

([Link to docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#execute(java.lang.Runnable)))

so my question is, does async execute block the ui thread? is my observations true.

thanks

**EDIT**

I am using [this library](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#execute(java.lang.Runnable)) to scrape TMDB data

```
 AsyncTask.execute(() -> {

            TmdbTvSeasons tmdbTvSeasons = new TmdbApi(apiKey).getTvSeasons();
            TvSeason season = tmdbTvSeasons.getSeason(
                    tmdbShowId,
                    seasonNumber,
                    "en",
                    TmdbTvSeasons.SeasonMethod.videos);

            listener.tvSeasonReceived(season);

        });
```

My listener then passes the result to the ui to update a recycler view:

```
 tListener = t -> {
                tArray.add(t)
                jobHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                jobHandler.post(() ->
                        adapter.notifyItemInserted(tArray.size() - 1));
            };
```

Comment: No, by itself, it doesn't. The issue is likely in your `Runnable` method.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @Dimness updated code

Comment: Just log out the current thread in your `Runnable` block, `Log.e("Thread", Thread.currentThread().name)` to confirm it is not `main` - looking at `AsyncTask` source it queues then runs on a ThreadPool using a `SerialExecutor`

Comment: @MarkKeen seems to return `AsyncTask #4`

Comment: The "ThreadPool using a SerialExecutor" is something i may need to look into how did you jump to the source code like that? I keep hitting the stub using intellij

Comment: I'm not familiar with that library or its behavior, but if you're adding too many items one by one, and calling `notifyItemInserted()` for each, that'll hang the UI, too. It would be better to add them as a batch, and notify only once. Also, creating a new `Handler` each time is a little inefficient, as well.

Comment: @MikeM. think I know what my problem is after MarkKee's response I was under the assumption AsyncTask.execute performed the operation in parallel but instead its sequential with a queue and the queue gets too long. Do you have any idea how I find the source code to see AsyncTask uses SerialExecutor? I keep reaching the stub `public static void execute(Runnable runnable) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }`

Comment: Well, [here's the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java#656), but if the problem is too many continuous updates, executing them in parallel won't help, and could possibly just make things worse. Also, there is no publicly available method to change `AsyncTask`'s default `Executor`, btw.

Comment: Okay thanks Mike youve been a lot of help, I wasted a lot of time trying to figure this out. ill now do a batch update instead of making a large queue

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask.execute runs on the AsyncTask thread.  So long as you don't call .get() (which you should never do) its asynchronous.  However you do not need to use runOnUiThread or posting to a Handler with it-  the entire point of an AsyncTask is that onPostExecute runs on the UI thread-  otherwise you'd just use a Thread.